# WCF Streaming takes too long

Tags: wpf, wcf, file-upload, streaming

I have enabled streaming in my code but still its taking long time to upload large files. Here is what happens :

My WPF code calls the service to upload the file but the debugger on the service is hit after a long time. For 10 MB file, it takes approx 1.07 mins.

Following is the code :

Calling code :

```
using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileInfo.FullName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
            {
                uploadRequestInfo.FileName = fileInfo.Name;
                uploadRequestInfo.Length = fileInfo.Length;
                uploadRequestInfo.FileByteStream = stream;
                clientUpload.UploadFile(uploadRequestInfo);
            }
```

Operation Contract :

```
public partial class RemoteFileInfo {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
        public string FileName;

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
        public long Length;

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/", Order=0)]
        public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

        public RemoteFileInfo() {
        }

        public RemoteFileInfo(string FileName, long Length, System.IO.Stream FileByteStream) {
            this.FileName = FileName;
            this.Length = Length;
            this.FileByteStream = FileByteStream;
        }
    }
```

app.config :

```
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                  realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
        </binding>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize it at the Service Contract level, by editing the Web.config of the Web application that hosts the WCF Service.

To point you in the right direction I would have to know a lot more information about the Web Services that the application hosts, etc. But it would be something along the lines of building a custom binding with:

- TCP Transport
- Binary Encoding